# Android x databinding

Tags: android, android-studio, android-databinding, androidx

I migrated my project to androidx and now I'm receiving errors for every databinding generated class because all these generated classes still use `import android.support.v7` instead of android x. So far I tried to delete all generated classes and rebuild project, but it generates same ones after building project. Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: typically I think the issue is more that the layout xml files still reference the `support` versions....I'm not sure to what extent the migrate tool is supposed to convert those but I found here I had to manually convert most of them

Comment: you mean manually add some dependencies? or change layout to use androidx?

Comment: change the layouts...using for example mapping shown in "Artifact mappings" section of https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Comment: delete the build folder from you app > build folder and clean and build your project again.

Comment: Perhaps some syntax could not be changed. Check uses of `android.support.v7` ctrl+shift+F and change them manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you have migrated to AndroidX, as you said your classes are still using the old imports. Android Studio doesn't seem to refactor it well enough for some reason. This happened to me too and I had to manually delete the invalid imports and add the `androidx` imports. (alt + enter) to add the correct imports after deleting the invalid imports.

Edit: you'll need to change the class imports as well as the full qualified names of the widgets in the xml layout, menu, etc. files.

Change `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`

To
`import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;`

Change `<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>`

To `<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>`